# command not found error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a code to count the number of word per line. Here is my code

```
num= $(echo $compareFile1 | wc -w)
```

Here `$compareFile1` contains each line. I am trying to get the number in `num` variable. But I am getting the following error

```
line 3: 6: command not found
```

where `6` clearly the number of word. I checked. but there is nothing in the `num` variable and also the error.
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should not be space after the `=` operator, that is:

`num=$(echo $compareFile1 | wc -w)`

Comment: thanks man. u just saved a life !!